# Non normal operator examples on Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying functional analysis with 'John B. Conway - A course in functional' analysis.

> In exercises 2.2.15, I proved if $A$ is a normal operator on $H$(Hilbert
>   space), $A$ is injective if and only if $A$ has dense range. But I
>   can't find examples  (1) operator $T$ such that $\ker T={0}$ but ran
>   $T$ is not dense and (2) operator $U$ such that $U$ is surjective but $\ker
> U\neq{0}.$

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $\ell^{2}$ define $S((x_n))=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$ and $T((x_n)) =(x_2,x_3,..)$. Then  $S$ is injective and its range is not dense; $T$ is surjective and its kernel is not $\{0\}$.